# coding style for If condition

Tags: c#, coding-style, coding-standards

I came across below style of writing if statements in C#, on msdn code examples. Usually when I write if statements, the conditions I would write `(Customer != null)

I want to know if there is any difference/gain in writing statement like below:

```
Customer customer;
if (null != customer)
{
  // some code
}
```

Or

```
if ("" != customer.Name) 
{
  // some code
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is legal in C# and is colloquially known as a [Yoda Condition.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013263/difference-between-null-x-and-x-null/7013280#7013280) Many people in the C/C++ world like this because it guards at compile time against replacing `==` with `=` by accident. However, it has fallen out of favor in C# due to the fact the compiler will flag it (the single `=`) as an error in that instance (so long as it's not a `boolean` eval).

Comment: The compiler will not warn you (I believe C compilers do that), it will error out.

Comment: @svick: thanks, you are absolutely correct. Just confirmed it.

Comment: I disagree with most/many. As that is totally subjective. It may be true from your perspective. But from my perspective (totally different to your): Many people in the C++ think this is a terrible idea. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/162256/in-c-and-c-what-methods-can-prevent-accidental-use-of-the-assignment-where/162258#162258

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure in C#, but in C++ it's legal to assign value inside a if statement.

Writing the `if` this way prevent you from bad surprises if one forgets one character: something like `if ( customer.Age = 15)`.

When inversing rhs and lhs it's not possible to assign customer.Age to the value 15 which is const.

So, probably the code you're reading was written by a former C++ folk.

But as MS Visual has warning for assignment inside ifs, I tend to never to write them this way.

Comment: In C# it is legal to have an assignment in the condition of an `if` statement only if the compile-time type of the assignment is (1) bool, or (2) a type which implements `operator true`. So `bool b = false; if (b = M()) { ... }` would be legal, but `int i = 0; if (i = M()) { ... }` would be illegal.